Find and Relace all JSON properties with single string?
I have a large JSON file where I want to find and replace all properies with the same string
How the JSON currently looks
{
 "example1": "some text1"
 "example2": "some text2"
 "example3": "some text3"
}

Ideal output for the JSON
{
 "example1": "hello"
 "example2": "hello"
 "example3": "hello"
}


That is not valid JSON. Are you planning to replace through programming? Or how? What is holding you back to do this replacement?

Neither the example input, nor the expected output are valid JSON. VSCode cannot help you, try jq.

ChatGPT helped me!
regular expression in VSCODE is (?<=":)\s*".*?"

To replace all values in your JSON file with the string "hello", you can use a simple script in JavaScript.
const fs = require('fs');

const jsonString = fs.readFileSync('yourfile.json', 'utf-8');

let jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);

for (let key in jsonObject) {
    if (jsonObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        jsonObject[key] = "hello";
    }
}

const newJsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject, null, 2);

fs.writeFileSync('yourfile.json', newJsonString);


This is a simple task for jq. The following jq script produces the expected output:
with_entries(.value = "hello")

See it online.
Install jq, then run this command in a terminal:
$ jq 'with_entries(.value = "hello")' input.json > output.json

... to process the JSON stored in the file input.json and save the output in the file output.json.
The output will be formatted on multiple lines (and you can open output.json and inspect it in VSCode or another editor). If you need the output on a single line (to save space), add option -c to the jq command line:
$ jq -c 'with_entries(.value = "hello")' input.json > output.json

